# GMAIL "Mail Service not Enabled"

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm facing a problem with Gmail API for sending emails.
I have organization: **example.com** where all Gmail services and disabled for all users.
I create a user-group **mailman@example.com** where I put some users that can use Gmail API to send emails.

According to GMAIL documentation you can Turn ON Gmail service only for specified User Groups or Organization. So I choose the fist one.

In the end, I still have errors that "**Mail service not Enabled**" for account "sender@example.com".

Any idea?

Ps. I setup all required permissions on GPC/GSuit and services accounts. In Admin Panel I see that GMAIL is enabled for that "mailman@example.com" user-group, but for individual user (from that group) GMAIL is turned OFF.

Is a chance that Organization level setting is overriding user-group level setting?

Thanks in advance

Comment: In case a Group has the Gmail Service `ON`, while for the other users outside the group is `OFF`, you should see the Gmail Service as `ON` in Users > User_in_group > Apps. Keep in mind that these changes can take up to ~24h to propagate.